# Flutter performance

Tags: performance, flutter, animation

I created an app that uses bottom navigation (3 pages).
the first and second page have a lot of buttons on them (approx. 20 to 30 Elevated buttons). the last page is a game that runs on a do..while loop with 4 buttons and at least 10 textviews that change dynamically.

I added page transition animations (sliding between bottom navigation views) and the issue I am running into is a small delay between transitions and I suspect it is due to the amount of buttons that need to be rebuilt every time I transition. Each page is a stateful widget. I use PageView and PageController.

I am asking for advice on how I can improve my apps performance while keeping all my buttons...
I added const on all my widgets (i.e Text, Icon and textstyle), I feel that it improved my performance a little...

Anymore suggestions?
Thank you in advanced!!

Comment: Just confirming you're judging the performance on `release` mode and not `debug` mode?

Comment: @Loren.A yes release mode and also did --profile too see if there was a difference....